# PHP changing language version

Tags: php

I have a website which i want to create other language version.
I don't want to create folder for each language. I was wondering it
it's possible to add a combobox on each page or on the main one
so that user can setup the language then using php i will 
check the option and show the right version. Any suggesting
to achive that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a combobox, when the user submits it, store the language in the session (`session_start();` has to be called) with `$_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['lang'];`. I'd advise you to whitelist languages as such:

```
session_start();

// define language whitelist
$allowedLangs = array('en', 'de');

// only store the new user language if it's an allowed one
if (isset($_POST['lang']) && in_array($_POST['lang'], $allowedLangs)) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['lang'];
}

// define the user language based on session data or use 'en' as default if not available
$userLang = isset($_SESSION['lang']) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : 'en';

// parse some language file according to the language
$translations = // TODO load some file with $userLang here
```

Of course you should adjust this to your own project and environment. For translation files, you can use a plain PHP file that returns an array like such:

```
<?php 
// en.php
return array(
    'some.key' => 'Translation',
);
```

Then if you include that file, the return value of the include will be the array, so in the above code you could do:

```
$translations = include 'translations/'.$userLang.'.php';
```

You then have to output all your text through this `$translations` variable, like `echo $translations['some.key']`.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to use cookies... in the lang files you would include an array of words or content to use.

```
 <?php

    if($_GET['language']){
        $lang = (string)$_GET['language'];
        setcookie("lang", $lang, time()+3600);
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        die();
    }elseif(!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
        $lang='en';
    }else{$lang=$_COOKIE['lang'];}

    switch($lang){
        case "en":
            include('./lang/en.php');
            break;
        case "fr":
            include('./lang/fr.php');
            break;
        case "pol":
            include('./lang/pol.php');
            break;
        default:
            include('./lang/en.php');
            break;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something along the lines of

```
if ($_GET['language']) {
  include $_GET['language'] . ".php";
}
```

and then save the languages in a php-file with there name, or a function depending on what you want to do with it

Comment: Cool, I get to include any file I'd like :)

Comment: i would not use this example `as is` due to any file can be included

Comment: well you could use a post instead to make it abit more secure that was more psevdo-code then for copy paste

Comment: People copy paste stuff from everywhere. You should always be careful when publishing code.

Comment: Even post is not secure. If you set up an array of all allowed values, you can check to see whether your input is in that array. If so, use that array element, if not, use a default language. Edit: See Saldaek's answer for more info.

Comment: Using `$_GET['language']` is fine. But maybe check that the language code is a valid RFC5646 code, and that the language file exists in  the correct folder? :) - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5646

Comment: yeah you're right Seldaek my bad

True Aether but lets  say you add "language/" infront of it, that way you only include files inside a dir that (atleast should) only contains the language-files

Comment: Even so, if someone puts a `../` at the beginning of their input, they can go up directory levels. You can add extra steps to prevent these things, but, at least for this case, it soon becomes much easier just to accept the input from a list of known-good options.

Answer (score 0):

hey for language version.
have languages in combobox.
maintain your current language in session.
When u change language call an ajax call Update the changed language into session and reload the page.

display page view with respect to session stored language.

thats it........