# Trouble While Changing Language of Multi-language script

Tags: php

I made a multi-language website .
It contains only two languages : English and French.
The default language is English and the second language is French
English works perfectly in the website but French doesn't because while changing the language to French using the URL (?lang=fr) I get random letters (in this case I got 'F') and if I switch to (?lang=de) I got 'D') it means that I get to first letter of the varibale $_GET["lang"]
This is the code of my lang.php file

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(isset($_GET['lang']))
 {
  $lang = $_GET['lang'];
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
  setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
 }

  else if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];}

  else if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];}

  else {$lang = 'fr';}

  if($lang=='fr'){$lang_dir = 'fr.php';}
  else if ($lang=='en') {$lang_dir = 'en.php';}
  else {$lang_dir = 'fr.php';}

  include 'administration/includes/lang/'.$lang_dir;

   ?>
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` in all your PHP files? Plus, where does `?lang=de` come into play, or was that for testing purposes only? It's not in your code listed above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's only in lang.php
?lang=de was just for testing purposes.

Comment: If it doesn't belong in there, either comment it out or delete it. That could be one of the problems. As far as I've been told, `session_start();` must reside in all called (PHP) files.

Comment: I tried to insert session_start(); in all called php files but this doesn't work !

Comment: Have a look at this, it may help > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276275/php-changing-language-version/6276488#6276488

Comment: I think that is similar to the code above !

Comment: Yes very similar. It's worked for me for something I've been building, I too build multi-lingual websites.

Comment: To add, I would suggest (if you can), to show your entire code(s) used. If I can't help, maybe someone else can; it's your choice.